# Not colored digits after characters in lstlisting code

Tags: listings, color, characters, code, literate-programming

I am writing a LaTeX document with Verilog code and I would like to have colored digits in these occasions:

- simple digits (for example `# 30`)
- bus (for example `[3:0]`)
- binary or hex representation (for example `4'hF`)

In addition, I wouldn't like to have colored digits in strings (`''`, `""`), after comments (`//`), and after characters (for example `i3` or `test_3mod`).

I have read other topics and I have solved the problem except the last one (digits in words or after characters).

I would appreciate it if anybody could help me.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel} % 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{courier} % font for code
\usepackage{kerkis}  % font for normal text
\usepackage{color}   
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Here i define the digits that i want to be colored orange
\newcommand\digitstyle{\color{orange}}
\newcommand\noncoldig{\color{black}}   %********************************
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ProcessDigit}[1]
{%
  \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode\relax%
   {\digitstyle #1}%
  \else
    #1%
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\NotDigit}[1]          %************************
{%
 \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode\relax%
  {\noncoldig #1}%
 \else
   #1%
 \fi
}
\makeatother
\lstset{literate=
    {0}{{{\ProcessDigit{0}}}}1
    {1}{{{\ProcessDigit{1}}}}1
    {2}{{{\ProcessDigit{2}}}}1
    {3}{{{\ProcessDigit{3}}}}1
    {4}{{{\ProcessDigit{4}}}}1
    {5}{{{\ProcessDigit{5}}}}1
    {6}{{{\ProcessDigit{6}}}}1
    {7}{{{\ProcessDigit{7}}}}1
    {8}{{{\ProcessDigit{8}}}}1
    {9}{{{\ProcessDigit{9}}}}1
    {.0}{{{\ProcessDigit{.0}}}}2
    {.1}{{{\ProcessDigit{.1}}}}2
    {.2}{{{\ProcessDigit{.2}}}}2
    {.3}{{{\ProcessDigit{.3}}}}2
    {.4}{{{\ProcessDigit{.4}}}}2
    {.5}{{{\ProcessDigit{.5}}}}2
    {.6}{{{\ProcessDigit{.6}}}}2
    {.7}{{{\ProcessDigit{.7}}}}2
    {.8}{{{\ProcessDigit{.8}}}}2
    {.9}{{{\ProcessDigit{.9}}}}2
    {'h}{{{\ProcessDigit{'h}}}}2
    {'b}{{{\ProcessDigit{'b}}}}2
    {A}{{{\ProcessDigit{A}}}}1
    {B}{{{\ProcessDigit{B}}}}1
    {C}{{{\ProcessDigit{C}}}}1
    {D}{{{\ProcessDigit{D}}}}1
    {E}{{{\ProcessDigit{E}}}}1
    {F}{{{\ProcessDigit{F}}}}1
    {\_4}{{{\NotDigit{\_4}}}}2,  %*********************** 
    morestring=[b]",
    morestring=[b]',
    morecomment=[l]//,
}

% Here i define the language
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} 
\lstset{language=Verilog, 
    basicstyle=\small\selectlanguage{english}\ttfamily,   
    breaklines=true,
    morekeywords={},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    morekeywords=[2]{1}, keywordstyle=[2]{\color{black}},
    identifierstyle=\color{black},
    commentstyle=\color{mygreen},
    showstringspaces=false,
    frame=single,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle={\small \color{black}},
    numbersep=9pt, 
}

% Here i define the caption
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Κώδικας \textlatin{Verilog}} % in english it means: Verilog Code

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption =\textlatin{\texttt{test\_4bit\_counter.v}}]
module test_4bit_counter (); // 4 must not be colored orange

  reg clk, s_s, ld, clr;
  wire [3:0] cnt;            // 3, 0 are correctly colored
  wire c0;                   // 0 must not be colored orange

  four_bit_counter inst0 (clk, s_s, ld, clr, dt, cnt, c0);
  // 0 must not be colored orange
  initial 
    begin
      # 5 clk <= 0; s_s <= 0; ld <= 0; clr <= 0; dt <= 4'hD;
    end  // all digits are correctly colored

  always # 10 clk <= !clk; // 10 is correctly colored
    initial 
      begin
        # 30 clr <= 1; // 30, 1 is correctly colored
      end

endmodule
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please extend your example to fully compilable TeX code with some example(s) in it covering your problematic issues? It would help a lot as Verilog code is not our daily bread. :-)

Comment: First of all, I would like to thank you for your interest. I have edited my post by adding a small example and all the packages needed. I have also added useful comments in latex and in the Verilog code example to inform you where there is a problem.

Comment: I haven't found a solution via the `listings` package. Would you mind a solution in Lua (preprocessing files with Verilog codes) before running TeX?

Comment: I have find a solution but you must declare the character with the digit not to be colored, you can see it in my code, i have make comments with *******. The idea is to declare a new command for black digits (like the one for orange) and declare which to get black. The problem is that I havent find a way to declare it general: e.g. x0, x1, x2, ..., x9, xA, ..., xF, where x is _, a, b, c, ..., A, B, C, ...

Answer (score 2):

It looks we cannot activate one-letter and two-letter sequences (`literate`) at the same time in the [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) package.

Therefore, I created a small patch in Lua. It takes input file written in Verilog language (let it be the `verilog-input.v` file starting with `\begin{lstlisting}` and ending with `\end{lstlisting}`), it finds critical spots and changes them. The output is written to the `verilog-output.v` file, which we can load in TeX by `\input verilog-output.v`. In the following example, I included the result directly into LaTeX file for easy comparison with the original version of the code.

In case we also want to run Verilog code (the input file), we would need to delete `\begin{lstlisting}[...]` and `\end{lstlisting}` parts and use the `\lstinputlisting` command (see e.g. pages 5 and 28 in the [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) manual) instead of the `\input` command.

I used common regular expressions in Lua. At a TeX level, I changed the colour of `identifierstyle` to red, so we can spot the differences from common text. The style for (underscore +) a digit is the same as a combination of `basicstyle` + `identifierstyle` set in the `\lstset` command. If we change colour in the `\maldigitstyle` command, we will identify those critical parts.

The key change is that I activated `mathescape` and then we can typeset anything in that area. The key command looks like this: `\def\maldigitstyle#1{{\color{red}\textrm{\ttfamily\small#1}}}`. One of the spots after modification looks like this: `module test$\maldigitstyle{\_4}$bit_counter ();`. As we can see, Lua snippet also changed underscore to `\_`, the reason is that underscore is becoming an active character again when we enter regular TeX environment.

I enclose both the files and a preview of the result. After we extract Verilog code into an input file, we run these two commands (any LaTeX engine can be used):

```
texlua verilog-convert.lua
lualatex mal-digits.tex
```

The Lua code is the `verilog-convert.lua` file:

```
-- A Lua snippet which converts _azAZ + digit sequence to a command.
-- texlua verilog-convert.lua

input="verilog-input.v"
output="verilog-output.v"

f=io.open(input, "r")
malcontent=f:read("*a")
--print(malcontent) -- an original version
f:close()

malcontent=unicode.utf8.gsub(malcontent, "([^\\])([_a-zA-Z][0-9]+)", function(s,t)
   print("Wrapping "..s..t.." into a command...")
   if string.sub(t,1,1)~="_" then s=s..string.sub(t,1,1); t=string.sub(t, 2) end
   --print(s,t)
   t=string.gsub(t,"_","\\_")
   return s.."$\\maldigitstyle{"..t.."}$"
   end -- function(s)
   )
--print(malcontent) -- a modified version

newf=io.open(output, "w")
newf:write(malcontent)
newf:close()
```

The TeX code is the `mal-digits.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel} % 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{courier} % font for code
\usepackage{kerkis}  % font for normal text
\usepackage{color}   
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Here i define the digits that i want to be colored orange
\newcommand\digitstyle{\color{orange}}
\newcommand\noncoldig{\color{black}}   %********************************
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ProcessDigit}[1]
{%
  \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode\relax%
   {\digitstyle #1}%
  \else
    #1%
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\NotDigit}[1]          %************************
{%
 \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode\relax%
  {\noncoldig #1}%
 \else
   #1%
 \fi
}
\makeatother
\lstset{literate=
    {0}{{{\ProcessDigit{0}}}}1
    {1}{{{\ProcessDigit{1}}}}1
    {2}{{{\ProcessDigit{2}}}}1
    {3}{{{\ProcessDigit{3}}}}1
    {4}{{{\ProcessDigit{4}}}}1
    {5}{{{\ProcessDigit{5}}}}1
    {6}{{{\ProcessDigit{6}}}}1
    {7}{{{\ProcessDigit{7}}}}1
    {8}{{{\ProcessDigit{8}}}}1
    {9}{{{\ProcessDigit{9}}}}1
    {.0}{{{\ProcessDigit{.0}}}}2
    {.1}{{{\ProcessDigit{.1}}}}2
    {.2}{{{\ProcessDigit{.2}}}}2
    {.3}{{{\ProcessDigit{.3}}}}2
    {.4}{{{\ProcessDigit{.4}}}}2
    {.5}{{{\ProcessDigit{.5}}}}2
    {.6}{{{\ProcessDigit{.6}}}}2
    {.7}{{{\ProcessDigit{.7}}}}2
    {.8}{{{\ProcessDigit{.8}}}}2
    {.9}{{{\ProcessDigit{.9}}}}2
    {'h}{{{\ProcessDigit{'h}}}}2
    {'b}{{{\ProcessDigit{'b}}}}2
    {A}{{{\ProcessDigit{A}}}}1
    {B}{{{\ProcessDigit{B}}}}1
    {C}{{{\ProcessDigit{C}}}}1
    {D}{{{\ProcessDigit{D}}}}1
    {E}{{{\ProcessDigit{E}}}}1
    {F}{{{\ProcessDigit{F}}}}1
    {\_4}{{{\NotDigit{\_4}}}}2,  %*********************** 
    morestring=[b]",
    morestring=[b]',
    morecomment=[l]//,
}

% Here i define the language
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} 
\lstset{language=Verilog, 
    basicstyle=\small\selectlanguage{english}\ttfamily,   
    breaklines=true,
    morekeywords={},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    morekeywords=[2]{1}, keywordstyle=[2]{\color{black}},
    identifierstyle=\color{red},
    commentstyle=\color{mygreen},
    showstringspaces=false,
    frame=single,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle={\small \color{black}},
    numbersep=9pt, 
    mathescape=true,
}

% Here i define the caption
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Κώδικας \textlatin{Verilog}} % in english it means: Verilog Code

% basicstyle+identifierstyle
\def\maldigitstyle#1{{\color{red}\textrm{\ttfamily\small#1}}}
\addtolength{\textheight}{3in}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-1in}

\begin{document}
% common loading of a file would be:
% \input verilog-output.v
\begin{lstlisting}[caption =\textlatin{\texttt{test\_4bit\_counter.v}}]
module test$\maldigitstyle{\_4}$bit_counter (); // 4 must not be colored orange

  reg clk, s_s, ld, clr;
  wire [3:0] cnt;            // 3, 0 are correctly colored
  wire c$\maldigitstyle{0}$;                   // 0 must not be colored orange

  four_bit_counter inst$\maldigitstyle{0}$ (clk, s_s, ld, clr, dt, cnt, c$\maldigitstyle{0}$);
  // 0 must not be colored orange
  initial 
    begin
      # 5 clk <= 0; s_s <= 0; ld <= 0; clr <= 0; dt <= 4'hD;
    end  // all digits are correctly colored

  always # 10 clk <= !clk; // 10 is correctly colored
    initial 
      begin
        # 30 clr <= 1; // 30, 1 is correctly colored
      end

endmodule
\end{lstlisting}

\ifx\relax % this is the original version
% common loading would be:
% \input verilog-input.v
\begin{lstlisting}[caption =\textlatin{\texttt{test\_4bit\_counter.v}}]
module test_4bit_counter (); // 4 must not be colored orange

  reg clk, s_s, ld, clr;
  wire [3:0] cnt;            // 3, 0 are correctly colored
  wire c0;                   // 0 must not be colored orange

  four_bit_counter inst0 (clk, s_s, ld, clr, dt, cnt, c0);
  // 0 must not be colored orange
  initial 
    begin
      # 5 clk <= 0; s_s <= 0; ld <= 0; clr <= 0; dt <= 4'hD;
    end  // all digits are correctly colored

  always # 10 clk <= !clk; // 10 is correctly colored
    initial 
      begin
        # 30 clr <= 1; // 30, 1 is correctly colored
      end

endmodule
\end{lstlisting} 
\fi % end of an original version

\end{document}
```

[image: An example of the output of the Lua snippet]

## A sequence for `literate`

In case, we would like to experiment with the code, this Lua snippet generates [underscore,letter] + digit combinations into the `mal-corr.tex` file). I am not using it at all, but it might be of some help. We run `texlua mal-corrector.lua`.

```
-- chrleft={ {65,90}, {97,122} }
chrleft={ {95,95}, {65,90}, {97,122} }
f=io.open("mal-corr.tex","w")

f:write([[\lstset{literate=
]])
for counter, outerlr in pairs(chrleft) do
for outer=outerlr[1],outerlr[2] do
for inner=0,9 do
-- print(outer,string.char(outer))
together=string.char(outer)..inner
f:write([[    {]]..together..[[}{{{\NotDigit{]]..together..[[}}}}2
]])
end -- inner
end -- outer
end -- outerlr
f:write([[}
]])
f:close()
```